# Xcode developing using remote compilers

Tags: c++, c, xcode, remote-debugging

I recently started to use Xcode as my primary IDE for C/C++ developing on MacOS M1 machine. On my linux virtual machine (gentoo arm64) I have toolchain for different architectures, such as arm, mips, mipsel, x86, powerpc etc. So, is there any way to compile my project by remote compilers. I've already figured out with coding on remote system with SSHFS, but what about using remote compilers?  Xcode version is 13.4

Comment: There is no such feature in Xcode IDE (you, of course, can run any arbitrary scripts as part of build steps, however)

Comment: What do you mean “compile my project by remote compilers”? Do you want to run a compiler that is on a remote system, so have a source file compiled via a network service? Do you want to use Xcode’s default compiler but specify switches to compile it for a non-native target architecture? Do you want to use a compiler on the current system but different from Xcode’s default compiler?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the requirement is, but maybe you can use ssh to invoke command line tools in the VM.

Comment: _I recently started to use Xcode as my primary IDE_ My sympathies

Comment: Well my project is on remote machine, so I want to compile it with remote compilers, and debug it with Xcode

Comment: Get your program working on your desktop before doing the remote stuff.  Developing on your local desktop is a lot easier and quicker than trying to do remote. This reduces the issues to only those related to remote stuff.